# Expandable listview group header color changes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set the two color for alternate group header in exapandable listview. But when I click multiple times to expand or collapse the color changes to any group row.

Here is my code,

```
 if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);

        if(groupPosition % 2 == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3C3C3C"));
        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
    }
```

This is happening after scrolling list. I have also tried this one

```
private int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#3C3C3C") };
int colorPos = groupPosition % colors.length;
convertView.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if(groupPosition % 2 == 0) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3c3c3c"));
        }else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
```

put this code outside the  if (convertView == null) this condition

Comment: Accept ans if you satisfy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if (groupPosition % 2 == 0) 
{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3C3C3C"));
} 
else
{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this.but Not working. Color changes but after scolling the colors shifts to any row.

Comment: First check : if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_group, null);
  }  then set code out side of If condition.

Comment: In my code     ::                                                                                                          if (convertView == null) {
LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
  }

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
if(groupPosition % 2 == 0)
```

instead of

```
if(groupPosition % 2 == 1)
```

And keep if condition outside of convertView==null check

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
}

if(groupPosition % 2 == 0) {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3C3C3C")); 
  }else {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
  }
```